# Android Bluetooth Low Energy sequential Write perfomance

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I do have a Bluetooth LE remote controlled car. Therefore i need to write periodically to a `drive` characteristic on the car. My microcontroller (AtmelXMega128A1 @ 32Mhz + nRF8001) should be able to handle up to 122 connections per second @ 7,5ms connection interval.

My Android App is based on cordova and a bluetooth low energy plugin: https://github.com/randdusing/BluetoothLE

I am running this on a Nexus 5 with Android v4.4.4.

I have a timer which sends values for steering and acceleration to the car each 175ms. I would like to send each 50ms but that does not work. I cannot tell where the problem is but i guess it is the android implementation of GATT (I get the pending command error at some level).

If i write more than it can handle the car executes all commands in a row but time shifted. Some queue hickup obviously and this is not the Microcontroller as it operates much faster.

I am doing a timing change which seems to be successful. I tried turning WiFi off as i hoped it would help but nothing changed.

Is there any experience on periodical writings to a GATT characteristics on Android? Examples would be great.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should make a robust design. Data should be driven by callback from the Android BT Stack telling when it's ready to accept more data (when the previous transmission is done). Do not use a timer. There will always happen need for retransmissions on the lower stack level so you cannot rely on an exact transfer interval and throughput.

The 7.5ms is the shortest possible connection interval however the default is usually much slower (48.75ms on my Nexus 5 with Android L) So from your peripheral you should try to request a faster connection interval once connected. This will speed up your throughput and responsiveness.

Some Android BT stacks refuse if you try to force a very fast connection interval. You should be handling that intelligently. Like trying with 7.5ms (parameter = 6) and increase it if it failed. iOS design guideline say you must not use a lower value than 20 (*1.25ms) and the upper request value should be at least 20 higher than the lower. You will get a faster connection parameter though if you request values min=10, max=20 and end around 18ms or something.
For android it seems most will accept the 7.5ms (value 6) but again you should not force it because the stack might cancel the connection then.

I made experiments on Android L, requesting connection intervals from the peripheral side when connected. Android rounded off requests so only every 3rd step gave a difference.
6=7.5ms, 9=11.25ms, 12=15.0ms, ..., 39=48.75ms which seems to be the default value on Nexus 5 running Android L.

Bluetooth is a shared resource in the broadcom chipset most are using on the smartphone side. Wifi, BT Classic, BT Low Enegy and sometimes GPS shares bandwidth. You will see hiccups and must be tolerant about them. Make a robust design.

Something else you can try is to renegotiate MTU-SIZE if you need larger data packages than the default. This is by specification an optional BLE feature however Apple broke it completely in iOS7 where they use it as a mandatory thing to boost up throughput. This broke all BLE devices which didn't implement the response handler and so it crashed and could never be used with iOS devices until a SW update was made. Baaaaaad. For android this is not a problem though.